# Send a string and Enter key to a Node.js script from command line

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line, process, inquirerjs

I am running a Node.js script in Linux that prompts (via [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer#inquirerpromptquestions---promise)) user for a code. I get the process id of the script:

```
pgrep -f test.js
```

and then pass it the code with a new line to simulate Enter key:

```
echo -e "1234\n" > /proc/88888/fd/0
```

The code `1234` gets passed, a new line is added as well, but it didn't trigger Enter key and the script does not proceed. However, when I manually press Enter key in shell, the script does recognise the Enter key. So the question is how can I reliably send Enter key to another process/script?

Following is the code of test.js script:

```
inquirer = require('inquirer');

async function plztest() {

let { code } = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'code',
        message: 'Enter code',
    },
]);
console.log(code);
process.exit();
};
      
plztest();
```

Comment: could you share the file you are feeding data to? so that any possible solution can be tested ?

Comment: added test.js code

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing the code snippet of the javascript file, I've got a solution for the same.

### The problem

is that you are a bit confused about the usage of pipes and redirections.

- **Pipe** `|` is used to pass output to another program or utility.
- **Redirect** `>` is used to pass output to either a file or stream.

A more detailed answer about pipes and redirections [is given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe)

### The Solution

Since now we know that we need to use pipes here, something like this would solve the problem.

```sh
echo -e "1234" | /proc/88888/fd/0
```

### Tests

I ran the script you have provided in the question, and the following are the output screenshots.
[image: Local Screenshots of script]

Comment: echo "123" | node app.js certainly works. But my use case requires `echo -e "1234" | /proc/88888/fd/0` and doing so gives me Permission Denied error.

Comment: However, `echo -e "1234" | tee /proc/88888/fd/0` worked, but still the script didn't recognise Enter command and thus does not proceed.